# Where to download the weights for PyTorch Efficientnet-b6

Tags: pytorch, finetuning

I would like to know how to download the weights for `PyTorch Efficientnet-b6` architecture. Only the weights, not the entire architecture.

Comment: The `EfficientNet-PyTorch` github repository from `lukemelas` has weights for the EfficientNet architecture, see [the releases section](https://github.com/lukemelas/EfficientNet-PyTorch/releases).

Comment: Now you can find implementation of EfficientNet on official github repo of PyTorch at https://github.com/pytorch/vision/blob/main/torchvision/models/efficientnet.py